# Make VIPs folder on OS X Mail the same as on iOS?

Tags: macos, mail.app

The VIPs folder on iOS and OS X seems to have very different behavior.

On iOS it shows only messages from VIPs that are also in the inbox.  On OS X it shows messages from all VIPs in every mailbox.

Is there any way to get the VIP folder in OS X to act like the one in iOS?

Answer (score 1):

It’s obscure:

1. expand the VIP mailbox so the mailbox list on the left shows all your VIPs — each one has a separate mailbox
2. go up to the View menu, select Sort By (!), and down the bottom you can choose Inbox Only or All Mailboxes

Notes:

- despite appearing to be specific to each VIP, the setting seems to affect all of them at once
- you seem to have to click off a VIP for the setting to show

Mail 8.2